# Return the names of all objects associated with R in a Databricks Notebook

Tags: r, object, azure-databricks, development-environment

My organization recently switched from running r in R-Studio to r in Azure Databricks.  I relied on R-Studio's environment pane quite heavily.  Is there a way to list the objects specifically associated with r in a Databricks' Notebook in a similar fashion to R-Studio's Environment Pane?

I have tried objects(), ls.str(), and ls(), all of which unfortunately return a number of objects specific to Databricks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate the issue by using `objects()` command in r notebook
I got the same issue, I am getting objects related to Databricks.

[image]

I get the objects associated with R we can execute str(list), head(df) like commands.

Sample :
I created three vectors using below code:

```
dbl_vec <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
chr_vec <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j')
log_vec <- c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
```

[image]

Created dataframe by using three vectors

```
library(tibble)
df <- data_frame(dbl_vec,chr_vec,log_vec)
```

and executed `str(df)`

[image]

For more commands you can refer [this](https://therbootcamp.github.io/BaselRBootcamp_2018April/_sessions/D1S2_Objects/Objects_practical_answers.html).